# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS "cal" cmd is not working

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation

I attempted to install 'ncal' using 'sudo apt install ncal,' but I encountered multiple errors:

[image: screenshot of errors]

I also tried 'sudo apt install command-no-found,' and the results were identical:

[image: Refer to the attached image for clarification].

Comment: You have a dependency issue. Most likely, you added some sources or PPA that isn't compatible. You need to know what you did to revert the error and fix `apt` state first (this is also known as "Dependency Hell").

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. Also, please [edit] your question and clarify if you are trying to install `cal` or `ncal`, they are not the same. Finally, your second screenshot suggests you tried to run `~sudo` which doesn't exist, not `sudo`. You want the command shown in the first error message: `sudo apt --fix-broken install`. The command `sudo apt install command-no-found` wouldn't do anything.